# Getting nodes without edges (When the N is larger than 60)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, networkx, minimum-spanning-tree

First I generated an NxN matrix of zeros and ones using NumPy. After that, I generated a copy matrix from the previous matrix, I replaced the ones in the first matrix with the weight of the edges. ( The matrix is symmetric and connected and undirected and its diagonal is zero like the original matrix) and I used BSF to check if it's connected and I found it connected every time. Then I used SciPy to find the MST (Minimum Spanning Tree). After that, I illustrated the MST using Network X

***for generating NxN Matrix of zeros and ones***

```
base = np.zeros((shape,shape))
for _ in range(100):
    a = np.random.randint(shape)
    b = np.random.randint(shape)
    if a != b:
        base[a, b] = 1
        base[b, a] = 1
```

***for generating NxN Matrix with the weight of edges***

```
# Fetch the location of the 1s.
Weightofedges = base
ones = np.argwhere(Weightofedges == 1)
ones = ones[ones[:, 0] < ones[:, 1], :]

# Assign random values.
for a, b in ones:
    Weightofedges[a, b] = Weightofedges[b, a] = np.random.randint(100)
```

***Find the MST using SciPy***

```
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import minimum_spanning_tree
X = minimum_spanning_tree(Weightofedges)
print("The Output Of The MST By Kruskal Algorithm:")
print("  Edges:    Weights:")
print(X)
print("-----------------------")
my_matrix3 = X.toarray().astype(int)
```

The Problem: When I input a matrix with a large number of nodes I got some nodes not connected with an edge
e.g.
Number Of Nodes equals 75
Number Of Edges equals 65
In the MST the edges must be N-1 where N is the number of nodes

This is the graph using N = 75 ( as shown there are nodes without edges )
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk0wy.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have created a weighted version of the [`Erdős–Rényi model`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model) - to be exact the ER model `G(n,M)` with n nodes and M edges. Currently, you have fixed M=100 and you observe for n>60 that your becomes disconnected. This is typical and (at least for the second ER model variant `G(n,p)` with n nodes and probability of an edge `p`) you can even calculate the threshold where you (almost surely) get a single/large connected component. But even without the math, you can intuitively see that it becomes difficult to connect 75 nodes with only 100 random edges.

I recommend that you check out the [`networkx`](https://networkx.org) package, if you want to do more with graphs on python. For example, the implementation of the `G(n,p)` variant: [`erdos_renyi_graph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.random_graphs.erdos_renyi_graph.html).